# Get posts from logged-in user

Tags: wordpress

I have two post-types. One is the parent post-type of the other. I'm currently trying to get the parent posts of the current logged-in user. The problem is that the array is getting all of the post parents. How can this be done? Thanks!

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_listing_type', 'my_add_meta_boxes' );


function my_add_meta_boxes( $post ) {

add_meta_box(
    'my-listing_type-parent',
    __( 'Media', 'example-textdomain' ),
    'my_listing_type_parent_meta_box',
    $post->listing_type,
    'side',
    'core'
);
}

function my_listing_type_parent_meta_box( $post ) {

$parents = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type'   => 'media', 
        'orderby'     => 'title', 
        'order'       => 'ASC', 
        'numberposts' => -1
        'post_author' => ???
    )
);

if ( !empty( $parents ) ) {

    echo '<select name="parent_id" class="widefat">'; // !Important! Don't change the 'parent_id' name attribute.

    foreach ( $parents as $parent ) {
        printf( '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', esc_attr( $parent->ID ), selected( $parent->ID, $post->post_parent, false ), esc_html( $parent->post_title ) );
    }

    echo '</select>';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you solved this or not but if you use the `wp_get_current_user()` function you will get the current users ID. Then you just need to tweak your `get_posts()` array slightly to ask for 'author' instead of 'post_author'.

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$parents = get_posts(
array(
    'post_type'   => 'media', 
    'orderby'     => 'title', 
    'order'       => 'ASC', 
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_author' => $user->ID
    )
);
```

Hope that helps